# Can a hypothetical question be chosen as a research question?

Tags: research-process, independent-researcher

Suppose, can I choose *"what would happen if the USA doesn't exist"* as a research question? Would this be still acceptable by a wider researcher community?

Comment: It's a terribly broad question. In what context are you asking it? Are you asking with reference to a particular group of persons? Are you asking about implications to global political dynamics? Global military dynamics? Regional military dynamics? Regional political dynamics? Economics? This is far, far too broad of an individual question IMO.

Comment: Thanks. @tonysdg

Sorry, it's a broad question. But suppose I want to discover the implications to global dynamics...and would it still be a research question?

My question is...is there any problem for a hypothetical question to be a research question?

Comment: Not at all - in a sense, every research question is a hypothetical question - or a *hypothesis*. Your job as the researcher (as I see it) is to offer credence to that hypothetical question and convince others - both in and out of the academic community - that (1) it's a valid hypothesis, and (2) you have some insight to offer into it.

Comment: One would need to be careful that your hypothetical was actually relevant to, and useful to, your particular community. In History, I suspect such a question would be deemed irrelevant. In political sociology, perhaps not (but your work would need to be based on that discipline). Just asking random counter-factual questions is not a good use of your time, and will be rightly rejected by your peers. Astrophysicist will scoff at my long detailed paper on the implications that the Magellan Cloud is made of Cheddar.

Comment: @JonCuster - I just want to point out that you missed a great opportunity to have a detailed paper on the implications that the Milky Way is made of caramel and chocolate.

Comment: @tonysdg - but NOT coconut - I hate coconut...

Answer (score 1):

At least in the hard sciences your question would not constitute a good research question. A scientific theory is considered a 'good' theory, if it makes falsifiable predictions (i.e. predictions which can be compared to observations of the real world) and has not been falsified despite comparing it to lots of observations.

Suppose in researching your question you come up with the theory "Hotdogs would never have been invented if the USA did not exist". This is not a good scientific theory, since it can not be falsified by comparing it to observations.

Things would be different, if it would currently *not be known* whether the USA exists or not. If in this case you can logically argue that "Hotdogs would never have been invented if the USA did not exist", this would constitute a valuable scientific contribution, since it would provide a link between the observation of Hotdogs and the existence of the USA.